# Assigning IP Addresses to a Physical Location

Tags: networking, ip, cisco, dhcp

Is there any way to assign an IP address to a computer connected a specific port on a level 3 Cisco switch? I would like to make a network map that can identify where computers are physically located in our building based on their IP address. If a computer moves locations, it gets a new IP address. That way an IP address is assigned to a physical location, and not a MAC address or computer.

Other ideas for being able to identify where computers are physically located would help, if my IP address idea is absurd.

Comment: Depending on what hardware you have, it might be absurd.  In any case, it will take a bit more than just remembering ip addresses.  You might be able to get away with naming your routers after their location and figuring it out with tracert.

Comment: That would work if we had proper organization on our switches. We have two sets of switches, one for the East side of the building, and one for the West side. Between them, they manage about 400 client machines and about 40 servers. The clients all go to the patch panels, but from there its almost random which switches they get to. It really needs to be redone, but that's what I am working with right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an IOS that supports [DHCP Server Port-Based Address Allocation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12.2_55_se/configuration/guide/swdhcp82.html#wp1320905) on your switch; you also must issue DHCP from your switch.  Assume that you have got `Fa1/0/1` and `Fa1/0/2` in Vlan120.

```
ip dhcp use subscriber-id client-id
ip dhcp subscriber-id interface-name
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.0.2.1 192.0.2.10
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN120
   network 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.0.2.1
   dns-server 192.0.2.5
   reserved-only
   address 192.0.2.101 client-id "Fa1/0/1" ascii
   address 192.0.2.102 client-id "Fa1/0/2" ascii
```

Comment: So with this the client plugged into Fa1/0/1 would get an IP of 192.0.2.101?

This might be exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: exactly, clients plugged in fa1/0/1 get 192.0.2.101

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you is to use DHCP Option 82 on your switch and configure DHCP Policy on Windows Server 2012.

For more information, look at this post [DHCP Policy on Windows Server 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/teamdhcp/archive/2012/08/22/granular-dhcp-server-administration-using-dhcp-policies-in-windows-server-2012.aspx)